# Javascript / JQuery Hide and Show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For some reason my jQuery hide and show are not working.  It seems to work but the items are not showing up on the page.   Possibly it could be a parent element with a position relative or display none, but I can't find anything. The code is shown below:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="newsItem1">
    <h4><a href="/news">News Title 1</a></h4><h4>April 6, 2015</h4>
    <p>Text here</p>
</div>

<div id="newsItem2">
    <h4><a href="/news">News Title 1</a></h4><h4>April 6, 2015</h4>
    <p>Text here</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#newsItem1, #newsItem2 {
    display:none;
}
```

**JS:**

```
 setInterval(NextNewsItem, 8000);
 var newsItem = 0;
 var numNewsItems = 2;

 function NextNewsItem() {
     newsItem++;

     if (newsItem > numNewsItems) {
         newsItem = 1;
     }

     console.log(newsItem);

     for (i = 1; i <= numNewsItems; i++) {
         console.log($("#newsItem" + i).css('display'));
         $("#newsItem" + i).hide();
         console.log($("#newsItem" + i).css('display'));
     }

     console.log($("#newsItem" + newsItem).css('display'));
     $("#newsItem" + newsItem).show();
     console.log($("#newsItem" + newsItem).css('display'));
 }
```

**The first iteration shows:**

> 1
>
> none
>
> none
>
> none
>
> none
>
> none
>
> block

Comment: What are you attempting to accomplish?

Comment: Have you tried .show() and .hide(), respectively?

Comment: I recommend using .toggle() instead of .hide() and .show(). $().toggle() automatically determines if the object is visible or not

Comment: Oh and, I just realized where the bug is. You think you iterate from 1 to 2, but you are really going all the way to 3. In the last iteration, i is incremented to 3 and then tested against your rule i<=NumNewsItems, which is false. After the cycle you try to show #newsItem3, which does not exist

Comment: Good point by @kecer, depending on the use case.

Comment: I'm not sure where the bug is: http://jsfiddle.net/eL0kh42r/

Comment: My conclusion is that the code is correct.  The div is position:absolute.  Must be something overriding it.

Comment: The code is correct.    The style was being overridden.   I made it more specific: $(".wrapper .main div#newsItem" + newsItem).show();

Answer (score 0):

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jmqpnq1r/1/)

This seems to be working fine for me

**HTML**

```
<div id="newsItem1">
    <h4><a href="/news">News Title 1</a></h4><h4>April 6, 2015</h4>
    <p>Text here</p>
</div>

<div id="newsItem2">
    <h4><a href="/news">News Title 2</a></h4><h4>April 6, 2015</h4>
    <p>Text here</p>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
 setInterval(NextNewsItem, 1000);

 var newsItem = 0;
 var numNewsItems = 2;

 function NextNewsItem() {
     newsItem++;

     if (newsItem > numNewsItems) {
         newsItem = 1;
     }

     for (i = 1; i <= numNewsItems; i++) {
         $("#newsItem" + i).hide();
     }

     $("#newsItem" + newsItem).show();
 }
```

***Note:*** The reason the style is set on all but the first is to let toggle change them.